# How to install Axis2 plug-in to Eclipse (for Android dev)?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, apache-axis

I got my Eclipse (Indigo Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149) installed and running for Android development. Now, I want to consume a WCF WebService (wsdl) in my Android app. As I learnt, this can easily be done using Axis2 plug-in for Eclipse. However, I had hard-time to install the Axis2 plug-in.

I understand there are similar questions already asked, but I couldn't make it work using all the suggestions, and there is no accepted answer either. That's why I created this new questions. It would be nice if somebody can tell which version is working one? or how to make the latest (1.6.1) work?

I do not understand the plug-in installation processs in Eclipse. I see p2 folder in my local drive under Eclipse, so I assume I could just extract the download to dropins folder, right?

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas Veithen
Thanks for your answer buddy. The 1.6.1 version was driving me nuts. I tested it both in a Mac and a Windows machine and the result was the same. It just would not work. I took your advice and got the 1.6.2-SNAPSHOT version and it shows up just fine now.

@miliu
No matter which version you are looking for, you need to get the Axis2 eclipse codegen plugin.

Here is the link to the page where you can find the 1.6.2-SNAPSHOT version:
https://builds.apache.org/job/axis2-1.6/lastStableBuild/org.apache.axis2$axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/

Download the axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.6.2-SNAPSHOT.jar at https://builds.apache.org/job/axis2-1.6/lastStableBuild/org.apache.axis2$axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/1.6.2-SNAPSHOT/axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.6.2-SNAPSHOT.jar and drop it in your dropins folder. The latest version of Eclipse should already have a dropins folder after you extract the downloaded archive. You should now see the Axis wizards in Eclipse after restarting.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers were not easily understood so I'm adding this for anyone reading this in the future.

*Taken from the [Axis2 website](https://builds.apache.org/job/axis2-1.6/javadoc/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html):*

> Download the ZIP file for the plugin you want to install.
>
> Extract the content of the plugins folder in the ZIP archive into the dropins folder (i.e. do not create a plugins folder under dropins).

Ps: Get the 1.6.2 version from this [link](http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.2/)

Answer (score 0):

The 1.6.1 version has a bug and doesn't work. Use 1.6.0 or 1.6.2-SNAPSHOT (which can be downloaded from [here](https://builds.apache.org/job/axis2-1.6/lastStableBuild/)) instead.

All recent versions of Eclipse use p2. You need to put the JAR files into the dropins folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I still can get any further. This is what I did. I downloaded 1.6.0 MS Windows Binary Distribution zip version from http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/download.cgi. There are 1488 files included, but I couldn't find any JAR file. How do I get this file? Also, I'm not sure where the dropins folder should be. Can it be anywhere? How does Eclipse or P2 know that?  I created one under eclipse folder and extracted everything I downloaded into this folder, but it doesn't work. Could you please give me more detailed guidance?

Comment: Me again...I tried to get the 1.6.2-SNAPSHOT following your link. There are quite a few files listed there. Which one do I suppose to download? Please give me detailed instruction. Your help is much appreciated.